# git heroku multiple computers workflow

Tags: git, heroku

This question is probably due to my lack of understanding something i should!
I made a rails app on one machine and deployed it.
then cloned it to another machine to make some changes from there.
went back to the first machine and created some branches to makes some changes...
I know want my first machine to have the heroku stuff.

whats the best strategy for this type of development on multiple machines as a single heroku user?

What I'm doing now is creating a branch, performing a git pull into that branch, then merging the changes....  sound right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git is a decentralized version control system where you can push up and pull down code repositories. The act of deploying to Heroku is synonymous with pushing code. Likewise, to checkout Heroku code, you can simply pull down code.

Although you could use Heroku as the place to push up and pull down your branches (and do all commits), I would strongly recommend that you setup a additional remote repository (I'd recommend [GitHub](https://github.com/)) where you do the majority of your code changes, and only use your Heroku repository for deployments. Then, you can merge and branches or changes into master before deploying.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense... I guess I wanted private repo without paying.  Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Now i'm running into publish error's.  I really have to move to github!